# Windows Form Designer thrown exception after changing Custom Control dll

Tags: .net, c++, visual-studio-2010, custom-controls, windows-forms-designer

After I have changed my dll containing my custom control I am getting warnings from the build

1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: Easy Labels, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.Targets(1360,9): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "ResizeLabel, Version=1.0.4056.28976, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.
1>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.Targets(1360,9): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "ResizeLabel, Version=1.0.4056.28118, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.
1>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.Targets(1360,9): warning MSB3243: No way to resolve conflict between "ResizeLabel, Version=1.0.4056.28976, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" and "ResizeLabel, Version=1.0.4056.28118, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null". Choosing "ResizeLabel, Version=1.0.4056.28976, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" arbitrarily.
1>  stdafx.cpp
1>  AssemblyInfo.cpp
1>  Easy Labels.cpp
1>  Generating Code...
1>  .NETFramework,Version=v4.0.AssemblyAttributes.cpp
1>  Easy Labels.vcxproj -> C:\Users\bobinski\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Easy Labels\Debug\Easy Labels.exe
========== Rebuild All: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========

There seems to be references to the earlier version as well as the new version.

I reset the toolbox, removed the new controls from the code, which surely should leave no reference to the dll, but the designer exception still occurs.

I'm obviously doing something basically wrong, but I've no idea what it might be.

I'm wondering if I should be using the GAC, but really advice on changing a dll safely is probably what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is a toolbox item which is an old version, deleting it, closing and re-opening the solution sorts it out.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you really should not need to do this, it happens.  I am assuming your custom control is included in the solution.  Close VS completely.  Go to your project folders and delete all the folders created by the build process - bin, debug, and release.  Reopen the solution (which should include the custom control).  Build and it should fix everything.  If you cannot include the control in the  solution, I think you may have to delete all references to it, then delete all the folders, then put it back in everywhere.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  It didn't work for me  unfortunately.

Comment: OOps, pressed return, didn't realise it would send my comment rather than going to next line of the box!  My dll was in a different solution and project, but I've changed it so that I have two projects in the one solution.  I still have a problem, but it's much more manageable.  After recompiling the dll, the reference in the forms project shows as broken until I remove and replace it.

Comment: Sorry to hear that.  Usually this fixes any sort of update problems 
I have had so far.

Comment: Hi again, you put me on the right lines, but when it happens I have to reset the toolbox, reset the references, close the solution and then it's OK again.  What a pain!

Comment: Ouch.  Does it happen often?  Maybe report it to Microsoft.  I am not using 2010 yet.  The 2008 ide gets confused occasionally, not very often so it is not a big deal.

Comment: Now I'm changing the references when I recompile the dll, I only have to close my solution and reopen it occasionally.